# How to connect hive and kibi

Tags: hadoop, hive, analytics, kibana, bigdata

Can anyone help me how to connect KIBI and HDFS?
I want to load data from hadoop file system into kibi  to perform analytics.
KIBI is a platform for data intelligence (analytics + exploration and search).

I am able to connect with elastic search, but unable to connect with hive.

Comment: Can you include relevant error messages? If this is a distributed system, can you confirm they can communicate via ping or other utility?

Comment: @Spechal For kibi , Elasticsearch is distributed filesystem itself. connecting KIBI and hadoop  can be done by elastic-hadoop connector . But i want to know is there any possibility to connect kibi directly with hadoop (via Pig, Hive, Spark) without elasticsearch ?